# Properly Nesting Arrays Within Objects In Bash

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, slack, slack-api

I'm building a Bash shell script to run as a post-build task in Jenkins.

This script sets some information conditionally and then sends it to Slack's Inbound Webhook API.

The information is sent via a cURL request, and the JSON object that I send can accept an `attachments` key which points to an array of objects.

This is how my code for the attachments array and overall JSON object

```
attachments="[\"{\"fallback\":\"This\u0020is\u0020a\u0020fallback\u0020message\u0020just\u0020in\u0020case\",\"color\":\"#36a64f\",\"author_name\":\"$author_name\",\"text\":\"$text\"}\"]"

json="{\"channel\":\"$channel\",\"username\":\"$username\",\"icon_emoji\":\"$emoji\",\"attachments\":\"$attachments\"}"
```

In Jenkins' console output, I'm seeing the following translation in my cURL request:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"channel":"#jenkinsslacktest","username":"Jenkins-Bot","icon_emoji":":rocket:","attachments":"["{"fallback":"This\u0020is\u0020a\u0020fallback\u0020message\u0020just\u0020in\u0020case","color":"#36a64f","author_name":"TestAuthor","text":":rocket:\u0020:rocket:\u0020SUCCESS!\u0020:rocket:\u0020:rocket:"}"]"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/link-to-my-webhook
```

In the way it's formatted, my webhook does not trigger appropriately and no message is sent into my chosen Slack channel.

If I replaced the `attachments` key/value pair and just placed the `text` line in its place, this call is successful.

It seems like I'm just not escaping or formatting this `attachments` value properly. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: You should start by figuring out what you want the end result to be, and only then try to construct that with your data. `"attachments": "[" {"..` is not valid JSON, regardless of whether it was written by a human or a bash script

Comment: You should be using `jq` to generate the JSON, instead of trying to use string interpolation to hobble it together.

Comment: Is the `attachments` value supposed to be a JSON string, or a JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue here is the JSON syntax of the `attachments` array. You need to remove the quotes around `[` and `]` to make it valid JSON syntax. Then it will work.

Here is the correct bash line:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"channel":"#jenkinsslacktest","username":"Jenkins-Bot","icon_emoji":":rocket:","attachments":[{"fallback":"This\u0020is\u0020a\u0020fallback\u0020message\u0020just\u0020in\u0020case","color":"#36a64f","author_name":"TestAuthor","text":":rocket:\u0020:rocket:\u0020SUCCESS!\u0020:rocket:\u0020:rocket:"}]}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/link-to-my-webhook
```

You can use a tool like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) or [JSONViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to verify your JSON syntax is correct.